# C++ copying list of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, list

I have Client* objects stored in my game. I want to pass a list to a Client. The Client object stores a list of Client pointers, and so the list I pass in I want to overwrite the stored list, but std::copy() is giving errors.

```
void Client::SetClientList(list<Client*> c) 
{ _clients.clear(); std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), _clients); }
```

It gives strange errors pointing to the xutility file. If I comment out the copy statement then it compiles fine so that's the statement that it doesn't like.

The idea is that each client stores a list of clients that are within range and therefore need to send data too.

Comment: Check the parameters of `std::copy` again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::copy` takes 3 iterators, not 2 and a container:

```
std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), _clients.begin());
```

Also, if they are the same list type then just do this:

```
_clients = c;
```